# Is there a way to prevent a process being created in UNIX-like system?

Tags: android, unix, process

Say there is an application with two process A and B. If I kill A, then B will create A. If I kill B, then A will create B. So if I want to kill this application completely, how to do this? For instance, in Android, some applications use this multi-processes method to keep it always running in background, which is annoying.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't really prevent a process to be created, as soon as there is space in the system for it (quota or not), a process is created if requested.

If you want to kill such "an application" you have to send a signal to both at the same time. If these processes are in the same group it is much easier as it is possible to send a signal to all processes in the group.

I'm not sure that the system you described work as is; I suspect that there is a `inetd`-like daemon that launch your process when they died. I think you are talking about Android Services Manager. Read about application life cycle in Android.